# Porque mi codigo while solo funciona una vez

Tags: c

En mi tarea me piden ingresar valores de tipo `int` y `float` pero al condicionar a que estos valores sean numéricos y el `int` mayor que 0 solo me deja un error y se cierra el programa ingreso un valor `"l"` y me vuelve el ciclo pero al poner este segundo valor sea letra me lo cierra y necesito que se repita hasta que sea valor numérico.

```
/* 1. Biblioteca estándar de C (Archivos incluidos) */
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int FILAS;

int COLUMNA;

float Xo;

int i=1;

/* 2. Definición de la función principal */
main() 
{
    
    printf("NEWTON HACIA DELANTE \n");


    /* 3. Definición del tamaño */
    printf("Define el tamaño de la tabla en funcion de filas (EN UN VALOR NBUMERICO)\n");
    scanf ("%d",FILAS); 

    while(FILAS>0 && isdigit(FILAS));
    {
        /* 3. Definición del tamaño */
        printf("Define el tamaño de la tabla en funcion de filas (EN UN VALOR NBUMERICO)\n");
        scanf ("%d",FILAS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El primer problema que tienes es que te falta un `&` en `scanf`:

```
scanf ("%d",&FILAS);
//          ^
```

`scanf` necesita **un puntero** para poder modificar la variable dentro de la función. si le pasas, como es el caso, una variable por valor, estarás modificando posiciones aleatorias de la memoria.

Por otro lado, `isdigit` espera recibir un **caracter**. Si dicho caracter se corresponde con un dígito numérico, entonces devolverá `1`. Si miras una tabla ASCII verás que los dígitos numéricos se corresponden con los siguientes valores numéricos:

```
'0' -> 0x30
'1' -> 0x31
'2' -> 0x32
'3' -> 0x33
...
```

Lo que hace tu código no es pasar un caracter a la función... le pasa **un número**.

Para tener un comportamiento equivalente, tendrías que introducir los números anteriores (pero pasados a decimal):

```
0x30 -> 48
0x31 -> 49
0x32 -> 50
...
```

Si a `scanf` le dices que vas a leer un número (`"%d"`), entonces `scanf` leerá únicamente dígitos numéricos y con ellos compondrá un único número codificado en base 2.

Si a `scanf` le dices que vas a leer un caracter (`"%c"`), entonces vas a recibir un único caracter codificado en ASCII, es decir, obtendrás un `char` que no es más que un número que se puede consultar en una tabla ASCII para saber a qué caracter corresponde.

Dado que tu has configurado `scanf` para leer números, lo que deberías hacer es verificar si `scanf` ha podido leer algo, ya que si no se han introducido números, `scanf` no va a poder leer nada:

```
printf("Define el tamaño de la tabla en funcion de filas (EN UN VALOR NBUMERICO)\n");
while (scanf("%d", &FILAS) == 0 && FILAS <= 0) // scanf devuelve el numero de elementos que ha leido
{
    printf("Define el tamaño de la tabla en funcion de filas (EN UN VALOR NBUMERICO)\n");
}
```

o, si prefieres poner el mensaje una única vez en el código:

```
do {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }

    printf("Define el tamaño de la tabla en funcion de filas (EN UN VALOR NBUMERICO)\n");
} while (scanf("%d", &FILAS) == 0 || FILAS <= 0);
```

Lo que hace este ejemplo es comprobar cuántos valores ha podido leer `scanf`. Como `scanf` solo tiene un parámetro, únicamente podrá retornar 0 o 1. Si retorna un 0 entonces es que no se ha introducido un caracter numérico. Adicionalmente también se comprueba que el número introducido es positivo.

El código del `while ((c=getchar() ...` sirve para limpiar el buffer de entrada y eliminar los caracteres no numéricos que se puedan encontrar en dicho buffer.

Comment: Creo que te fuiste un poco por las ramas y no destacaste que el error es que se olvidó el `&` y de consumir los caracteres no numéricos.

Comment: @Mateo dado que `FILAS` es de tipo `int`, no vi la necesidad de leer un `char` (o un `string`), comprobar que todo eran dígitos numéricos y finalmente convertir a entero. Lo del & sí que lo vi, pero me lié con lo otro y se me olvidó mencionarlo :(